# Python from Windows to Centos -> import msvcrt getch issue

Tags: python-3.x, centos7

I have a stupid question I think.

I have a script develloped on Windows but the goal is to run it on a Centos Server 7. The script work well on windows but not on Centos.

I have this error :

```
[root@114697 scripts]# python3.6 synch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "synch.py", line 9, in <module>
from msvcrt import getch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msvcrt'
```

My script start with this :

```
from __future__ import division
import websocket
import thread
import time
import random
import sys
import json
import pymysql
import datetime
from time import ctime
from time import sleep
from msvcrt import getch
from pprint import pprint
import os
```

Seems `msvcrt import getch`come from Microsoft ...
Can some one help to solve this problem please ?

*Note : Python 3.6 is not involved, it was compiled in a clean way on the server.
Seems*

Yoki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation for the `msvcrt` module, the first two sentences have this to say:

> These functions provide access to some useful capabilities on Windows platforms. Some higher-level modules use these functions to build the Windows implementations of their services.

Since Centos Server 7 is not Windows, you will need to find an alternative approach to `getch`.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks @Noctis Skytower

Do you know how i can make it ?
Do you know an alternative ?

Comment: @OuimaisnonToiy You may be able to come up with an alternative after looking at the implementation for [`unix_getpass`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/getpass.py#L29) and comparing it to [`win_getpass`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/getpass.py#L97) (which uses [`msvcrt.getwch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getwch)).

Comment: Solved ! I just remove [from msvcrt import getch]

Answer (score 0):

Solved ! I just remove

```
from msvcrt import getch
```

In fact in don't need to interact with the script on Centos ... it is a deamon :)